# Extracting a key from a dictionary to another dictionary in Python

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a big python dictionary. One of its keys has another dictionary as the value. I want to create a new dictionary using the values and then delete the key from my original dictionary.

Is there any function to export the values into another dictionary? To delete I know I can use the `.pop()` function. I tried googling but wasn't successful.

This is the dictionary. I used stars to block out sensitive information. The key I need is `billing_address`, which has another dictionary as the values:

```
{
    'shipping_cost_tax': '0.0000',
    'refunded_amount': '0.0000',
    'external_source': None,
    'discount_amount': '0.0000',
    'base_wrapping_cost': '0.0000',
    'shipping_cost_tax_class_id': 2,
    'payment_method': 'PayPal',
    'handling_cost_ex_tax': '0.0000',
    'store_credit_amount': '0.0000',
    'shipping_cost_inc_tax': '11.0000',
    'handling_cost_tax_class_id': 2,
    'currency_id': 1,
    'payment_status': 'captured',
    'subtotal_ex_tax': '99.0000',
    'total_inc_tax': '11.0000',
    'handling_cost_inc_tax': '0.0000',
    'total_ex_tax': '11.0000',
    'is_deleted': False,
    'status_id': 5,
    'id': 614534,
    'shipping_cost_ex_tax': '11.0000',
    'date_shipped': '',
    'order_source': 'www',
    'status': 'Cancelled',
    'handling_cost_tax': '0.0000',
    'items_total': 3,
    'wrapping_cost_tax': '0.0000',
    'date_created': 'Wed,
    09 Jul 2014 12:22:17 +0000',
    'total_tax': '0.0000',
    'order_is_digital': False,
    'date_modified': 'Thu,
    30 Oct 2014 02:34:07 +0000',
    'geoip_country': 'Australia',
    'base_shipping_cost': '11.0000',
    'payment_provider_id': '**************',
    'staff_notes': '',
    'default_currency_id': 1,
    'currency_code': 'AUD',
    'currency_exchange_rate': '1.0000000000',
    'coupon_discount': '99.0000',
    'customer_message': '',
    'subtotal_inc_tax': '99.0000',
    'gift_certificate_amount': '0.0000',
    'items_shipped': 0,
    'default_currency_code': 'AUD',
    'customer_id': 1,
    'geoip_country_iso2': 'AU',
    'ip_address': '124.168.160.136',
    'shipping_address_count': 1,
    'wrapping_cost_ex_tax': '0.0000',
    'base_handling_cost': '0.0000',
    'wrapping_cost_tax_class_id': 3,
    'ebay_order_id': '0',
    'wrapping_cost_inc_tax': '0.0000',
    'billing_address': {
        'state': '*******',
        'street_1': '*************',
        'street_2': '',
        'country_iso2': 'AU',
        'last_name': '************',
        'company': '***************',
        'country': 'Australia',
        'first_name': '*********',
        'email': '***************',
        'phone': '*************',
        'city': '*************',
        'zip': '************'
    },
    'subtotal_tax': '0.0000'
}
```

EDIT:

```
def popAndMergeDicts(line):

    tempDict = line['billing_address']
    del line['billing_address']
    for i in tempDict:
        line[i] = tempDict[i]
    print(line)


def process_file(filename):
    lines = tuple(open(filename))

    for line in lines[0:1]:
        popAndMergeDicts(line)

process_file('allOrdersData')
```

allOrdersData is a file where I have many dictionaries like the one I posted before, one in each line. I get the following error when I try to run it:

TypeError: string indices must be integers

EDIT 2:

Nevermind, got it working with ast.literal_eval:

```
import ast


def popAndMergeDicts(line):

    dictLine = ast.literal_eval(line)
    tempDict = dictLine['billing_address']
    del dictLine['billing_address']
    for i in tempDict:
        dictLine[i] = tempDict[i]
    print(dictLine)


def process_file(filename):
    lines = tuple(open(filename))
    for line in lines[0:]:
        popAndMergeDicts(line)

process_file('allOrdersData')
```

Comment: Ain't there no any sample?

Comment: Added the data I said.

Comment: A new dictionary with the keys and values from the billing_address key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `.pop()`: it returns the value it pops. Eg,

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import pprint

big_dict = {
    'shipping_cost_tax': '0.0000',
    'refunded_amount': '0.0000',
    #etc
    'billing_address': {
        'state': '*******',
        'street_1': '*************',
        'street_2': '',
        'country_iso2': 'AU',
        #etc
    },
    'subtotal_tax': '0.0000'
}

print 'Before'
pprint.pprint(big_dict, indent=4)

bill_dict = big_dict.pop('billing_address')

print '\nBill dict'
pprint.pprint(bill_dict, indent=4)

print '\nAfter'
pprint.pprint(big_dict, indent=4)
```

**output**

```
Before
{   'billing_address': {   'country_iso2': 'AU',
                           'state': '*******',
                           'street_1': '*************',
                           'street_2': ''},
    'refunded_amount': '0.0000',
    'shipping_cost_tax': '0.0000',
    'subtotal_tax': '0.0000'}

Bill dict
{   'country_iso2': 'AU',
    'state': '*******',
    'street_1': '*************',
    'street_2': ''}

After
{   'refunded_amount': '0.0000',
    'shipping_cost_tax': '0.0000',
    'subtotal_tax': '0.0000'}
```

---

To keep the keys/values in the original dictionary, instead of creating a new one, you can do what Marichyasana suggests:

```
bill_dict = big_dict.pop('billing_address')
for k in bill_dict:
    big_dict[k] = bill_dict[k]
del bill_dict

print '\nAfter'
pprint.pprint(big_dict, indent=4)
```

**output**

```
After
{   'country_iso2': 'AU',
    'refunded_amount': '0.0000',
    'shipping_cost_tax': '0.0000',
    'state': '*******',
    'street_1': '*************',
    'street_2': '',
    'subtotal_tax': '0.0000'}
```

I've also deleted the temporary `bill_dict`. That's not strictly necessary, as `bill_dict` will automatically be deleted once it goes out of scope.

Comment: I'm getting another error now. It worked when I do it for just one dictionary, but it fails when I try loop through a file with many dictionaries. I'll update my question with the code I have so far.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to *reference* the "sub-dictionary", you could simply use (where `d` is your **original** dictionary):

```
billing1 = d['billing_address']
```

If you want a distinct, separate copy, you could use any of the following:

```
billing2 = dict(d['billing_address'])
billing3 = d['billing_address'].copy()
billing4 = copy.copy(d['billing_address'])  # after import copy
```

Changes to values in `billing1` will be reflected in your original dictionary.  Changes to values in the other three *will not* be reflected in your original dictionary.

If you want to delete the `billing_address` key also (like you suggest in your question but backpedal on in your comments), then use one of the above approaches first, followed by:

```
del d['billing_address']
```

Or, as one step, if you're committed to deleting the key from your original dictionary, use [`dict.pop()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.pop)

```
billing5 = d.pop('billing_address')
```

Answer (score 1):

Let 'a' be the name of the dictionary
Let 'b' be the name of the billing_address dictionary

```
b=a['billing_address']
del a['billing_address']
for i in b:
    a[i]=b[i]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ans = {key:val for key, val in input_dict.pop('billing_address').items()}
```

Comment: That did it. Would it be possible for me to keep the keys/values in my original dictionary, instead of creating a new one? Not sure if I should ask this here or create another question.

Comment: This will not delete the `billing_address` key from your original dictionary.

Comment: This method is inefficient. Why not just `ans = input_dict['billing_address']`? Or `ans = input_dict.pop('billing_address')`?

Comment: See my answer for making a new dict and adding its contents to the original.

Comment: @iamfbpt: Changing the question after it already has answers is discouraged on SO (we call it a chameleon question), but we'll let you get away with it this time. :). Marichyasana has answered your modified question, but I've also updated my old answer.

Answer (score -1):

```
dict1 = {'shipping_cost_tax': '0.0000', 'refunded_amount': '0.0000', 'external_source': None, 'discount_amount': '0.0000', 'base_wrapping_cost': '0.0000', 'shipping_cost_tax_class_id': 2, 'payment_method': 'PayPal', 'handling_cost_ex_tax': '0.0000', 'store_credit_amount': '0.0000', 'shipping_cost_inc_tax': '11.0000', 'handling_cost_tax_class_id': 2, 'currency_id': 1, 'payment_status': 'captured', 'subtotal_ex_tax': '99.0000', 'total_inc_tax': '11.0000', 'handling_cost_inc_tax': '0.0000', 'total_ex_tax': '11.0000', 'is_deleted': False, 'status_id': 5, 'id': 614534, 'shipping_cost_ex_tax': '11.0000', 'date_shipped': '', 'order_source': 'www', 'status': 'Cancelled', 'handling_cost_tax': '0.0000', 'items_total': 3, 'wrapping_cost_tax': '0.0000', 'date_created': 'Wed, 09 Jul 2014 12:22:17 +0000', 'total_tax': '0.0000', 'order_is_digital': False, 'date_modified': 'Thu, 30 Oct 2014 02:34:07 +0000', 'geoip_country': 'Australia', 'base_shipping_cost': '11.0000', 'payment_provider_id': '**************', 'staff_notes': '', 'default_currency_id': 1, 'currency_code': 'AUD', 'currency_exchange_rate': '1.0000000000', 'coupon_discount': '99.0000', 'customer_message': '', 'subtotal_inc_tax': '99.0000', 'gift_certificate_amount': '0.0000', 'items_shipped': 0, 'default_currency_code': 'AUD', 'customer_id': 1, 'geoip_country_iso2': 'AU', 'ip_address': '124.168.160.136', 'shipping_address_count': 1, 'wrapping_cost_ex_tax': '0.0000', 'base_handling_cost': '0.0000', 'wrapping_cost_tax_class_id': 3, 'ebay_order_id': '0', 'wrapping_cost_inc_tax': '0.0000', 'billing_address': {'state': '*******', 'street_1': '*************', 'street_2': '', 'country_iso2': 'AU', 'last_name': '************', 'company': '***************', 'country': 'Australia', 'first_name': '*********', 'email': '***************', 'phone': '*************', 'city': '*************', 'zip': '************'}, 'subtotal_tax': '0.0000'}

print {'billing_address': dict1['billing_address']}
```

Comment: Consider adding some explanation to your answer. However, it appears that this code does not do what iamfbpt wants to do.